# $Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject when inject cdi bean to jax-rs controller

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, weblogic12c, javassist

I am trying to create a Jax-rs controller and injecting a CDI bean into this contoller but application gives the following exception.

It works fine when i dont inject the bean.

The project also uses Hibernate and it has javassist dependency. When i remove this dependency, i can inject the bean into the controller without a problem but of course hibernate not working in this situation.

What might be causing this exception?

I am using weblogic 12.1.3 server.

This is the service bean i want to inject

```
@Named("AccountBcImpl")
public class AccountBcImpl extends AccountBaseBcImpl implements AccountBc {
   ...
}
```

This is the jax-rs controller

```
@Named
@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
@Path("/build")
public class BuildCotroller {

    @Inject
    private AccountBc accountBc;



    public String getBuilding(@QueryParam("buildId") Long buildId) throws BaseException {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000830 Unable to load the cache value for the key Managed Bean [class com.aaa.bbb.web.rest.BuildController] with qualifiers [@Default @Any]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:621)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aaa.bbb.web.rest.BuildController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2234)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3969)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4829)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:71)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aaa.bbb.web.rest.BuildController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:249)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel guilty making this an answer because it is more of a general gut feel since I've never used javassist.  But your problem sounds like it might be a jar conflict.

Anyone using maven really should have as part of their build the ENFORCER plugin.  It is a HUGE pain because most projects will take about half a day to eliminate all the conflicting transitive dependencies the first time you run it.  It will make you wonder how any program ever worked without it.

Anyhow for what it's worth here is a pom snippet that will allow you to run the enforcer:enforce goal as well as binding itself to the VALIDATE goal.

```
<!-- THIS IS THE ENFORCER PLUGIN FOR MAVEN enforcer:enforce GOAL -->
        <!-- SPECIFIC GOALS VS LIFECYCLE GOALS MUST HAVE THE EXECUTION ID default-cli -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <DependencyConvergence/>
                            <bannedDependencies>
                                <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </bannedDependencies>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- THIS IS THE ENFORCER PLUGIN FOR MAVEN VALIDATION GOAL BUILDS -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <DependencyConvergence/>
                            <bannedDependencies>
                                <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
                                <!-- Excludes are a list of includes that must NEVER be used -->
                                <!-- BOTH explicity and implicitly - They are completely forbidden -->
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                               </excludes>
                            </bannedDependencies>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```